# Print a column without 1st item of that column

Tags: linux, awk

Good night everybody, i want to print a column without printing the 1st item of that column.

I want print the 4th column of this csv file:

```
ID;Curso;AnoNasc;MediaAcesso;Salario;IndiceSatisfacao
1;Psicologia;1994;18;750;3
2;Psicologia;1992;17;754;4
3;Psicologia;1991;13;780;4
4;Psicologia;1993;11;900;4
```

So i do this:

```
system("awk -F ';' '{print $4}' DBcursos.csv > ficha02exer08-mediaacesso.dat");
```

But this print:

```
MediaAcesso
18
17
13
11
```

But i only want the numbers, so i want to print all except the first line (MediaAcesso), how can i do this? Can i do this with AWK?

Thank you!

Comment: Exactly, i want print the 4th column without 1st element of that column, in this case without "MediaAcesso"

Comment: Yeah, now i know that... I just started using awk today, so i'm kind a noobie with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think of it as skipping the first element of a column, you just want to skip processing the entire first row of the file. So check the record number and only process records after that one.

```
awk -F ';' 'NR > 1 {print $4}' DBcursos.csv > ficha02exer08-mediaacesso.dat
```

Comment: That's it!! Thank you so much.